# what to do if sbt compile goes on indefinitely?

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt

I am using sbt 1.6.2 with Scala 3 on a very small code base of 5 files and a few hundred lines of code. Sometimes it compiles fine within a few seconds, and other times it goes into some infinite loop, showing

| => root / Compile / compileIncremental 677s

I can't even figure out how to stop it. I tried control-c and control-d, but neither works, so I end up having to kill the shell. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, weird. Can you run it in verbose mode and put the logs here? If it runs fine sometimes and sometimes does not, I guess the problem is not from your code

Comment: In such cases I would always update everything to the latest version. Latest sbt version is 1.7.1, latest Scala version is 3.1.3.

Comment: You probably hit a bug somewhere. Thus, I would first update everything to their latest versions as Matthias suggested since the underlying bug may have already been reported and fixed. If not, then try to minimize it as much as you can and then open a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I updated sbt to 1.7.1 and compiled. It worked fine. But then I added an obvious bug for testing and tried to compile again. It reported the bug, but then it went into an apparent infinite loop once again, and I had to kill the shell again. Someone please tell me how to compile in verbose mode.

Comment: this is an issue still open: [https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6183](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6183)